# GCP on-demand VM disconnects "Server Connection Error" while running computation

Tags: google-cloud-platform

I run the workbench notebook on an on-demand VM of GCP. Every two or three days I get the following error during computation:

> Server Connection Error
>
> A connection to the Jupyter server could not
> be established. JupyterLab will continue trying to reconnect. Check
> your network connection or Jupyter server configuration.

All work is lost. I find it weird as on-demand VM is not suppose to disconnect.

[image]

What are some possible causes?

Answer (score 1):

Using preemptible VMs have 24 hours of use or the tokens use. That inherited security feature makes the Notebooks not suitable for long running jobs since it will make you refresh the Notebook and cause the executing cells to lose state.

While Having an On-demand VM this shouldn’t be happening. I can think of 3 possible things that could be happening:

- Something happens (such as: Network Interrupt, User session
  expiring).
- Jupyter invalidates that session and creates a new one.
- The notebook page changes to no kernel.

Some workarounds to mitigate this are:

- Use [Vertex AI
  Training](https://cloud.google.com/vertex-ai/docs/training/custom-training)
  to create a model using custom training.
- Use [Vertex AI Workbench notebook
  executor](https://cloud.google.com/blog/products/ai-machine-learning/schedule-and-execute-notebooks-with-vertex-ai-workbench),
  as it will use a Notebook as a Training Job.